# Veinte y * vs. Veinti*

Tags: pronunciación, ortografía

Which is more commonly used to say twenty-two?

> veinte y dos

or

> veintidós

I know for numbers above 30 that the first example is always the case. I am also wondering about 16-19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form is *veinti-*. The *Real Academia de la Lengua Española* (Royal Achademy of Spanish Language), RAE, publishes this and more things on [its web page](http://www.rae.es/).

**A list of numbers, where your answer is**, is in:

(numerales cardinales) http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rqV8h362gD62vc21qB

Which comes from:

(numerales) http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8I7I4TmGLD6lWITzaL

All about numbers in spanish:
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS

All this information is in the [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/) -*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* (Panhispanic dictionary of questions). Try to check it whenever you have a question, it's very useful. Also the [DRAE dictionary](http://lema.rae.es/drae/) will help you very much.

Comment: Posting answers that mainly have links is discouraged on SE.  You should try to develop your answer applying what is in those links.

Answer (score 4):

*Veintidós* is by far the most common as that matches the pronunciation of (as far as I know) every single Spanish-speaker.  It used to be acceptable to say *veinte y dos* and you'll probably see it still once in a while, but as of the 2002 DPD, they are considered antiquated and recommended to be avoided though not strictly incorrect.<sup>1</sup>  It's curious to note that the 22nd DRAE defines *veintidós* as *veinte y dos*, but in accordance with the DPD's recommendations, the 23rd DRAE changes that to *veinte más dos*.

Writing *diez y seis* in separate words is even more outdated because the *diez* component is at this point completely destressed.

Also, numbers above 30 *may* be written as a single word, just make sure you don't omit the *-a*: *treintaicinco*, *sesentaisiete*, *noventaiún<sub>/uno/una</sub>*.

---

<sup>1.  I would only recommend it if you're a native and actually pronounce the *e* in *veinte* and/or realize two separate fully stressed syllables as in *véinte y siéte*.  These days, most everyone destresses the first syllable (*veinte y siéte*) and raises the *e* (*veinti ̮y siete*), both of which are cause for merging into a single word.  If you do either, or if you are a non native, you should only ever consider using the single word.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

*veintidós* (22) is correct, *veinte y dos* is not.
It is written in a single word (always) from *dieciséis* to *veintinueve*.

http://www.donquijote.org/spanishlanguage/spanish-numbers/